# Link "name-your-price" with "add_to_cart" shortcode woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a "name-your-price" product (ref https://woocommerce.com/products/name-your-price/)

On the product page it displays a input box where the user can enter the product price followed by the add to cart button.

Shortcode used

```
[product_page id="xxxx"]
```

This is working as expected.

However when I use the [add_to_cart] shortcode for displaying the product it displays as
    Suggested Amount: $0.00 / month followed by Add to Cart button without any input box to accept user value

Shortcode used

```
[add_to_cart id="xxxx"]
```

Is it possible to add the input box with the add_to_cart ShortCode ?

Comment: No. You'd need to implement your own shortcode.

Comment: Hi Rishi,Did you end up getting this sorted out? I'm looking into the same thing at the moment, and looking for an easy solution. Might have to make my own short code i guess.

Comment: Well what I did was the following...
Removed the product description &
Wrapped the product page in tabby responsive plugin
so the final layout was close to what was required